# how to get current entry info in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i have a table in mysql

```
ques_id (auto increment , primary) , 
ques_title (string)
```

By using eloquent

```
$qinfo = new Question ; 
$qinfo->ques_title = "xyz" ;
$qinfo ->save() ;
```

i want to know what will be `ques_id` of the above entry . 
`$qinfo->ques_id` is not working .

Eloquent :

```
class Question extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'questions';
    public $timestamps = false ;
    protected $primarykey = 'ques_id' ;
}
```

table schema

```
mysql> desc questions ;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| ques_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| ques_title | varchar(200)     | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Is your id column 'id' - or have you specifically set it to 'ques_id'?

Comment: specifically set to ques_id ,as table allows only one auto_increment column .

Comment: What do you mean "$qinfo->ques_id is not working" - your code above works for me?

Comment: $qinfo->ques_id is not returning any value , ideally it should return current incremented value .

Comment: Can you please paste the full row from your table or the schema of the table?

Comment: added the full detail . pls look into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `Question` model is something like this:

```
class Question extends ELoquent {

    //public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'questions';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ques_id';

    // ...

}
```

Now if you try this (that you have already tried) then it should work:

```
$qinfo = new Question; 
$qinfo->ques_title = "xyz";
$qinfo ->save();
```

The `ques_id` of the newly created model could be retrieved using this:

```
dd($qinfo->ques_id); // an integer
```

Comment: It does (I did it) and if it's not working then you made any mistake, try to find it.

Comment: i updated the detail , do i need to run any command after changing model class

Comment: Oh! It's a typo, glad it worked. Updated it with `K` :-)